# phonegap page transition issue

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am making a simple application in which I have an image with an image map, and when I click on the image map another page loads. I am using the href property in the tag to navigate to the new page. All of this is being done on a single page.

When I click on the image map the transition should be smooth and the second page should get loaded (this is what the natural behavior should be) but what I am getting is that the page transition is choppy and also the second page isn't loaded, nothing is displayed on the screen, and the elements are displayed only after I tap a couple of times on the screen.

I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find anything.

The earlier application that I had built never ad such an issue, and all of a sudden this issue came up in the second application.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>India Stats</title>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="listPage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            Geo-spatial Analysis of Election Results in India
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div>
                <img id="Image-Maps_8201304300944558" src="img/indiamap.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_8201304300944558" />
                <map id="_Image-Maps_8201304300944558" name="Image-Maps_8201304300944558">
                <area shape="poly" coords="60,255,78,258,94,262,106,281,120,294,124,301,117,304,117,313,110,317,108,325,108,334,106,343,99,343,97,351,87,347,88,338,86,329,85,319,85,311,81,305,79,315,78,324,68,329,54,337,46,337,43,333,33,325,29,316,21,310,20,303,17,299,28,298,36,296,43,293,43,288,34,288,25,290,17,285,14,279,14,272,14,265,23,258,36,262,45,262,50,258,58,263," href="#gujarat" />
                </map>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            Datanet Analytics &copy; Datanet India Pvt. Ltd.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gujarat" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            Geo-spatial Analysis of Election Results in Gujarat
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div>
                <img id="ImageMap" src="img/gujarat.png" usemap="#ImageMaps"/>
                <map id="ImageMaps" name="ImageMaps">
                  <area shape="poly" coords="225,348,224,337,219,332,219,328,212,324,204,319,197,317,191,314,193,310,201,306,199,300,202,295,198,291,194,287,196,283,195,277,187,275,182,275,177,275,165,274,158,274,158,278,158,285,163,297,169,309,171,317,158,316,150,313,145,313,139,313,134,316,134,320,141,328,149,336,156,342,165,345,178,352,187,356,195,356,206,354,212,354,223,351" href="#junagadh">
                </map>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            Datanet Analytics &copy; Datanet India Pvt. Ltd.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="junagadh" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            Geo-spatial Analysis of Election Results in Junagadh PC 2009 & ACs 2012
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <img src="img/junagadh.png" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
        <li style="font-size:30px"><a href="election.html">Analysis of Election Results</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:30px"><a href="cr.html">Constituencies Result of Previous Years</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
            Datanet Analytics &copy; Datanet India Pvt. Ltd.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="cordova-2.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I usually use a single 'index.html' file, and multiple js files to control the pages. If I have 10 Pages I will define 10 Divs. I manage the content through inner html ( calling the div id ) . It works well

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp yes Exactly. JavaScript object is lose when we are navigate one HTML page to other HTML page.

Comment: I am also using a single 'index.html' file, and a div for each page and calling each page by calling the respective div's id.

but still this problem is there.

Comment: @RahulJain Could you pl post some sample code here?

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp edited with index.html code

Comment: First always add a jQuery Mobile tag when discussing it. Mainly because problem is usually in it. SEcond, you should use jQuery Mobile page events to detect if second page has been successfully loaded. In case you are doing some ajax call or any dynamic page generation during the page transition then you are doing it wrong. You always do it in a first page, they initiate transition and show second page. Every action that prolongs ttransition will make your app look bad.

Comment: Well before posting my comment I should have asked you do you do any content generation/ajax retrieval during the page transition?

Comment: @Gajotres no I am not doing any ajax retrieval during the page transition. Its just a simple transition of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Debug the Application. where error arises.Like @Gajotres have said.If your second page is not loading then there are might be some issues into the second Page or You can use jQM 
`$.mobile.changePage('#secondPage',{transition:"none"});` method to solve this problem. I have faced similar kind of issue. but i have removed all the transition from the application.Its working fantastic.You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="cordova-2.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please add these lines before body load i.e. in '< head >' tag and remove them from bottom of the page, then try to load your page again. JS files should be loaded before body load so that functions can be applied. :)